# ResourceType Warning in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I know I have a very vague request, so if you haven't experienced the following error it is probably not worth continuing to read.

Since I downloaded the 4.1.2 SDK for Android my App is producing a warning in LogCat(Eclipse):

```
Failure getting entry for 0x010802c0 (t=7 e=704) in package 0 (error -75)
```

The warning did not appear when I started coding for SDK 4.0.3.

There is no further information on the warning, which makes it hard to find out, just where that warning is originating. 
Has anyone of you had a similar problem and can give me a hint where to look?

I am sure the problem lies in some xml file, but wether it's layout or style or strings, I have no clue. 
I also have no idea how to perform a meaningful trial and error search because the project has gotten quite complex.
Is there a way to determine which resource is sought under that adress?

I've been searching the web and especially stackoverflow.com for a hint or solution, have found nothing, all similar post have at least another information to circle in the cause of the warning.

Well, thanks in advance for any assistance.

**Edit:**
Just by chance I removed the Logcat filter for my app and watched the rest of the system logging, it turns out it is not only my app which produces this warning message.
I guess it has to do with Samsungs version of Android that is running on the phone?

If there is no further interest in this topic within a decent time I guess I'll delete the question...

Comment: Did you try doing a clean and rebuild?  I've also seen errors that were unresolvable without creating a new project and copying the source and resource files across ... something to do with changes in the project template

Comment: Hmm.. clean and rebuild is done a lot, yes, every time I write some more code into the source files. I haven't tried creating a new project yet...

Answer (score 0):

If there are people coming to this page, because of the same error, its not only a Samsung thing. In my case, the problem happened, because I tried to call `setLocale` in an Activity which extended `PreferenceActivity` and implemented `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. This lead to a Loop of the error mentioned above. Hope it helps :)